# My landscape android application turns to the portrait and crash

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have landscape large android app. All activities have `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"`. This app is created for work with some specific devices.
Main app use case is next:

1) Connect device to your phone through USB

2) You will see menu for choosing app to work with the device.

3) Select app and use it.

Problem is next:

When I connect device, when my app is already running, and choose my app. It turns to portrait orientation and crash in few seconds.

I try to reproduce this case at several phones. It reproduces on android 9+ with "Rotate off" only. At other phones app rotates to portrait for a moment, and instantly rotates back to landscape(crash is not happened).

I do not know if it useful, but last logs dependent on my app at logcat is this:

```
E/GLContextMgr17: OpenGL destoryed
E/GLYUVSurface: OpenGL destoryed
E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
E/GLContextMgr17: OpenGL destoryed
E/GLYUVSurface: OpenGL destoryed
E/Lightbridge: startStream videoCtlobjet == NULL
```

Comment: Why don't you use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Comment: If the above suggestion does not resolve your error, I'm happy to remove the dupe mark.

Comment: @NileshRathod `landscape` orientation give the same result